# Working with subreport that used multiple tables in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I created a subreport that use multiple tables (3 tables) and to update and delete data from a table.[image]

Below is the Form to update and delete that subreport data.
[image]

When I clicked on the Edit button, all the data loaded on the form but the first combobox was not load data. See below image[image: ![enter image description here]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxEGS.png)

Here is the code I wrote for Edit Button

```
> Private Sub EditState_Click()
>     If Not (Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
>         With Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset
>              Me.cbState = .Fields("State")
>              Me.cbCategory = .Fields("Category")
>              Me.cbYear = .Fields("Year")
>              Me.Ctl4 = .Fields("4")
>              Me.Ctl5 = .Fields("5")
>              Me.Ctl6 = .Fields("6")
>              Me.Ctl7 = .Fields("7")
>              Me.Ctl8 = .Fields("8")
>              Me.Ctl9 = .Fields("9")
>              Me.Ctl10 = .Fields("10")
>              Me.Ctl11 = .Fields("11")
>              Me.Ctl12 = .Fields("12")
>              Me.Ctl1 = .Fields("1")
>              Me.Ctl2 = .Fields("2")
>              Me.Ctl3 = .Fields("3")
>              
>             Me.cbState.Tag = .Fields("State")
>             'Change caption of Save Button to Update
>             Me.savestate.Caption = "Update"
>             'Change Edit Button to hidden
>             Me.EditState.Enabled = False
>             
>             
>         End With
>     End If End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us the row source of the combo box. Quite possibly, you just can't set that value because it isn't in the row source.

Comment: This is the row source of that First Combo box that I can't set that data from subreport.

"SELECT [States].[ID], [States].[State] FROM States ORDER BY [State];"

Comment: Below is the row source for subreport.

`SELECT States.State, Categories.Category, StateBudget.Year, StateBudget.[4], StateBudget.[5], StateBudget.[6], StateBudget.[7], StateBudget.[8], StateBudget.[9], StateBudget.[10], StateBudget.[11], StateBudget.[12], StateBudget.[1], StateBudget.[2], StateBudget.[3]`

Comment: What's the bound column on that combo box? (hint: it should be 2 but probably is 1)

Comment: bound column is 1!

Comment: Set it to 2 (because column 2 contains your state names, and you're setting it to a state name), and it should be fixed

Comment: Harleluya!!! It's work.
Thank @ErikvonAsmuth